# awk, sed, or grep command to output boolean file for each word in file1 to check if it's existent or not in file2

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have two files, if the word in file 1 is not existent in file 2, I want to generate the word false in the corresponding line in a new file say file 3. Otherwise, I want to output true in the corresponding line.

file 1:

```
a
b
c
d
```

file 2:

```
a
d
c
e
t
y
```

file 3:

```
true
false
true
true
```

Is there a way to do that using awk/sed/grep commands?

Comment: You got several answers, please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming file2 isn't empty and isn't so huge that it can't fit in memory without causing problems:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} {print ($0 in a ? "true" : "false")}' file2 file1
```

Comment: If file1 is small and file2 is huge, you can save file1 in an array (with a corresponding inverse array), process file2 to count the occurrences in the file1 array, then use END to output the file1 list.

Comment: Yup. Unless file1 is also huge... :-). Or you can sort both and use getline on one while reading the other, or sort them then join piped to sed or...

Comment: Re-sequencing is a bad idea. The output relies on a one-to-one correspondence between file1 and file3, Sorting anything makes the output useless, unless you also contrive to retain enough data to re-sort file3 in the final phase. The whole requirement design is questionable.

Comment: Yes, I'd use a DSU approach to retain the input order if I had to sort file1. But I don't really think any of that's going to be necessary in this case.

Comment: Helps if we are told which is the needle and which is the haystack, else we are just clutching at straws. I have been known to write (and test) all three algorithms in one script, and pick one at runtime depending on actual file sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Read `man grep bash`, and do something like UNTESTED:

```
for pat in $(cat "file 1") ; do
  ans="False"
  grep --quiet  "^$pat\$" "file 2" || \
    ans="True"
  echo -e "$pat\t$ans" >>"file 3"
```

Comment: Is that reading file2 for every line in file1 ? For shame !

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Of course the algorithm should change if "`file 1`" and/or "`file 2`" is HUGE, but Questioner didn't specify. For reasonably sized files, they'll fit in disk cache, and will be "memory quick", except the first time ("disk slow"). This in not a problem with modern computers. It was, back when I started (1967), but there have been improvements in buffering and caching since then.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -le '
  # construct a partial regex from the first filename argument
  my $re = join("|", split /\n+/, do { local(@ARGV,$/) = shift; <> });

  # complete and pre-compile the regex
  $re = qr/\b(?:$re)\b/;

  # read and process stdin and/or remaining filename args
  while(<>) {
    print /$re/ ? "true" : "false"
  }' file2 file1 
true
false
true
true
```

This perl script reads in the entire file indicated by the first argument (`file2`) and constructs a single regular expression that matches the individual words on each line of the file. Each word in the regex is separated by the `|` alternation character.  It assumes that the file contains one word per line and that lines are separated by one or more newline characters (which has the useful side-effect of ignoring blank lines).

NOTE: Each word of `file2` will be interpreted as a regular expression.  If you want them to be interpreted as fixed strings, change the `my $re ...` line to:

```
my $re = join("|", map { quotemeta $_ } split /\n+/, do { local(@ARGV,$/) = shift; <> });
```

The quotemeta function "quotes" all regexp metacharacters in a string so that they lose their special meaning and are treated as literal characters.  See `perldoc -f quotemeta`.  The `map` function causes the `{ quotemeta $_ }` block to be applied to each element of the list returned by `split`.  See `perldoc -f map` and `perldoc -f split`.

BTW, `do { local(@ARGV,$/) = shift; <> })` is a fairly common perl idiom for "slurping" a file, i.e. reading in an entire file at once. There are many other methods to do the same thing, including modules like [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Slurper), but this is simple and portable and doesn't require any library modules to be used or installed.

The script then uses the `qr` quoting operator to pre-compile the regex to improve performance (recompiling the same regex on every pass through the loop would be an enormous waste of CPU time).  Word-boundary markers, `\b`, are used to prevent partial matches, and `?:` is used to prevent capture of matches (which would just waste time since we only need to detect that a match occurred and don't need to use the matches for anything).   See `perldoc -f qr` and `man perlre`

The regex is case-sensitive, but could be made case-insensitive with the `i` regex modifier:

```
$re = qr/\b(?:$re)\b/i;
```

The script then reads any remaining input and, for each line of input, it prints "true" if the line matches the regex and "false" otherwise.  Because it uses the `while(<>)` it will read data from stdin and/or any filename arguments.  In this example, it reads the input from `file1`.

Memory usage is proportional to the size of the first file - the more words in `file2`, the more RAM it will use.  Run-time is, of course, proportional to the size of the first file and all other input.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your second file into a `sed` program:

```bash
$ sort -u file2 | sed 's:.*:s/^&$/true/; t:'
s/^a$/true/; t
s/^c$/true/; t
s/^d$/true/; t
s/^e$/true/; t
s/^t$/true/; t
s/^y$/true/; t
```

This `sed` program replaces the lines from `file2` with the string `true`.  The script immediately skips to the end using `t` if a substitution is performed; otherwise, the next substitution is attempted.

For this to work, the input in `file2` obviously can't contain anything that could be interpreted as a regular expression.  It also can't contain the character `/`.

Executing this on the first file, and adding a last substitution that defaults to replacing the line with the string `false`, we get

```bash
$ sort -u file2 | sed 's:.*:s/^&$/true/; t:' | sed -f /dev/stdin -e 's/.*/false/' file1
true
false
true
true
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
tmp=$(mktemp)
comm -2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) \
| sed -e 's/^\t.*/true/;t
  c false' > "$tmp"

paste <(cat -n < "$tmp") \
  <(cat -n file1 | sort -bk2) \
| sort -bk3,3n | cut -f2
```

Output:-

```
true
false
true
true
```

---

Notes:

- First step we sort both files and run them through comm with the second file suppressed.
- Next sed will identify the true/false elements
- Finally to recover the original order, we run a paste on output and numbered sorted input.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ for i in $(<file1.txt); do grep -oq "$i" file2.txt && echo true || echo false; done
true
false
true
true

$ xargs -i sh -c 'grep -oq "{}" file2.txt && echo true || echo false' < file1.txt
true
false
true
true
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash

find_in_array() {
  local string=$1
  shift
  for element in "$@"; do [[ "$element" == "$string" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}

readarray -t arr1 <file1.txt
readarray -t arr2 <file2.txt

for str in "${arr1[@]}"; do
    find_in_array "$str" "${arr2[@]}" && echo true || echo false
done
```

output

```
true
false
true
true
```